# Rails, Devise, Pundit - authorise Profile created from Devise registration controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, pundit

Feel free to say if you think something is wrong. 
I extended Devise Registration controller to create a Profile object to every new user:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    resource = build_resource({})
    resource.profile = Profile.new
    resource.profile.user_id = @user.id
    respond_with resource 
  end
```

They both are `has_one` - `has_one` related and in database:

```
create_table :profiles do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user, index: { unique: true }, foreign_key: true
end
```

So to get the right profile of current user, I must:

```
private 
  def set_profile
    @profile = Profile.where(user_id: current_user.id).first 
  end
```

And this kinda solves the problem - seems other users cant go around this query and access other profiles (or CAN THEY?), but for other resources I use [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) to control authorisation, so now it feels a bit messy.

So thats one concern. Other - I still don't know how to act when there is no user logged, because if visiting any restricted resource, this:

```
private
 def set_some_resource
 end
end
```

Throws - "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass) - how is best to avoid this?

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to start by reading the [Rails guides on assocations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

To create a one to one association you use `belongs_to` on the side with the foreign key column and has_one on the other.

```
class User
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile
  belongs_to :user
end
```

ActiveRecord then automatically links the records together. In general you should avoid setting ids (or getting associated records by ids) explicitly and instead use the assocations:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # ...
  def new
    # calls Devise::RegistrationsController#new 
    super do |user|
      user.profile.new
    end
  end
end
```

Devise is pretty nifty and lets you pass a block to tap into the flow instead of copypasting the whole action.

Simularily you would fetch the current users profile with:

```
private 
  def set_profile
    @profile = current_user.profile
  end
```

You can set if the callback should be called by using the `if:` option.

```
before_action :set_profile, if: :user_signed_in?
```

But if the action requires authentication you should make sure that it is after `:authenticate_user!` anyways which will halt the filter chain.

> And this kinda solves the problem - seems other users cant go around
>   this query and access other profiles (or CAN THEY?), but for other
>   resources I use Pundit to control authorisation, so now it feels a bit
>   messy.

You don't need to use Pundit to authorize creating a profile or fetching the current users profile. Since the profile is fetched via the user the is no way for another user to access it (well without hacking).

what you might want to authorize is the show, index, edit etc actions if you create a `ProfilesController`.

Comment: Note that adding the profile in the new action does not save the profile. You have to use fields_for and nested attributes if you want to user to pass params for the profile or call `super { |user| user.profile.create! }`  in the create action if you want to create it without parameters.

Comment: I replaced `belongs_to` with `has_one` because since Rails5, `belongs_to` adds `required: true` validation and upon user creation I get error - "user must exist". Your `super do |user|` block looks promising but I get "undefined method new for nilClass". Any thoughts?

Comment: No you can’t just swap belongs_to for has_one. Belongs to should be used on the side that has the foreign key. You can set “required: false” to skip the validation.

Comment: And sorry I was thinking of a has many association - for has_many or belongs to you can do user.profile = Profile.new

Comment: Ok, so changing the flag was what I needed... Can't understand why I didnt realise it yesterday... But your block throws an error - "undefined method new for nilClass". It works only as in my post. Any thoughts here?

Comment: I removed `resource.profile.user_id = @user.id` - was unneeded. Thanks for help!

Comment: p.s. adding `required: false` sounds wrong, but I decided to create Profile in the next registration step, so will leave this.